# How to restrict fragment from adding to top of stack if it already exist in the top of stack in android

Tags: android-fragments

Is there any way that i can achieve the launch mode single top feature in activity with fragment. Actually what i need is if there is any fragment exist on the top of the stack and if i am trying to add again, it should point to the same one which is already available on the top of the stack.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get fragment which is on top of the stack by this way 
getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()-1)

Check if this is same as your fragment or not.